# Use STRING_AGG to get Values from 3 different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation, string-agg

I am trying to get comma-separated values from the following 3 tables:

**Teams**: Id

**Players**: Id, Name

**TeamsPlayers**: Id, TeamId, PlayerId

What I am trying to get is a result like this:

| TeamId | PlayerNames |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ronaldo,Rivaldo,Ronaldinho,Dida |
| 2 | Riquelme,Messi,Aguero,DiMaria |

```
sql

SELECT STRING_AGG(Name, ',')
FROM (
    SELECT tp.TeamId, p.Name
    FROM Players p
    JOIN TeamPlayers tp ON p.Id = tp.PlayerId
    GROUP BY tp.TeamId, p.Name
    )
```

Comment: Why are you using a derived table (with an alias, which will cause an error)? YOu just need to aggregation on the name, as you're there. There's even an [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#d-return-news-articles-with-related-tags) of exactly what you need.

Comment: **without** an alias (nitpick police...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Larnu's comment.

Asssuming your initial query has the proper elements

```
SELECT tp.TeamId, 
      ,Names = STRING_AGG(p.Name, ',')
 FROM  Players p
 JOIN TeamPlayers tp ON p.Id = tp.PlayerId
 GROUP BY tp.TeamId
```